# React Parent state changes when copied from child state changes. How do I prevent this?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have a parent component. Marketplace.js code-

```
export default function Marketplace() {

const [filters, setFilters] = useState(
        [
            {
                id: 'commodity',
                name: "Commodity",
                isSelected: false,
                type: "select",
                options: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                value: null,
                availableFor: ['classifieds', 'auction']
            }
        ]
    );

return (
    <div>
        <FilterBar filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters} />
    </div>
)
```

The child component FilterBar.js code-

```
export default function FilterBar({ filters, setFilters }) {

    var copiedFilters = [...filters]
    const [newFilters, setNewFilters] = useState(copiedFilters);

    const onFilterChange = (e, item) => {
        if (e.target.value === '') {
            item.isSelected = false;
        } else {
            item.isSelected = true;
        }
        item.value = e.target.value;

        const updatedFilters = newFilters.map((filter) => {
            if (filter.id === item.id) {
                return {
                    ...filter,
                    isSelected: item.isSelected,
                    value: item.value,
                };
            } else {
                return filter;
            }
        });

        setNewFilters(updatedFilters);
    };

    ......

}
```

When setNewFilters() is used to set some new values, the 'filters' state passed from parent is also changed.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you might be mutating state. Can you show us where you call `setNewFilters`?

Comment: @NicholasTower I have added it in the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state when you change the item's `value` and `isSelected` props. Just do this instead:

```
const onFilterChange = (e, item) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const isSelected = !e.target.value === '';

  setNewFilters((prevNewFilters) => {
    return prevNewFilters.map((filter) => {
      return filter.id === item.id ? {
        ...filter,
        value,
        isSelected,
      } : filter;
    });
  });
};
```

When you do:

```
var copiedFilters = [...filters]
```

You are creating a new array, but the items inside it are exactly the same, so you are still referencing the original state from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use JSON to get a deep copy:

```
var copiedFilters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filters));
```

Changing `copiedFilters` now shouldn't change `filters` or any of it's values.

Comment: Tried this. It works the first time that page is loaded. But any subsequent executions of onFilterchange() fn is changing the 'filters' state.

Comment: Could you show the code where `onFilterchange` is called or assigned in your JSX?